# Creating a URL from parsed arguments

Tags: php, wordpress

Say you have an array built using wp_parse_args().  Is there a built in method in Wordpress to create a url using said array, or would I have to resort to a custom function?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the 'said' array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has a function bulit-in to convert arrays to query strings: [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

Here's an example:

```
$arr = array('name' => 'Eric', 'age' => 23, 'sex' => 'M');
$query = http_build_query($arr); // 'name=Eric&age=23&sex=M'
$url = 'http://example.com/?'.$query;
```

Comment: Looks simple enough!  Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you don't have a specific function like that in WP.
However, I think you can solve your problem and get the current URL (including args) using this code:

```
global $wp;
$current_url = add_query_arg( $wp->query_string, '', home_url( $wp->request ) );
```

Note that you can replace the '' parameter, to even add your own parameters if needed.

If for some reason that code doesn't meet your requirements, the answer to your question might be something like:

```
$args = wp_parse_args();
$str_params = '';
foreach($args as $key => $val) {
  $str_params .= ($str == '') ? "?" : "&";
  $str_params .= $key . "=" . $val;
}
$current_url = home_url( $wp->request ) . $str_params;
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking I'd end up having to do; build the URL inside a foreach.  Looks like there's a build query in PHP I didn't know about though.  See selected answer.